# Numpy load part of *.npz file in mmap_mode

Tags: python, numpy, upload, numpy-memmap

I know there already exists a similar question, which has not been answered.

I have a very large numpy array saved in a npz file. I don't want it to be loaded completely (my RAM can't handle it entirely), but just want to load a part of it.

This is how the file was generated:

```
np.savez_compressed('file_name.npz', xxx)
```

And this is how I would like to load it:

```
xxx = np.load('file_name.npz,mmap_mode="r")
```

Now, to actually access the part of the array I am interested into, I should type

```
a = xxx['arr_0'][0][0][0]
```

But though this piece is quite small, python first loads the whole array (I know it because my RAM is filled) and then shows this small part. The same would happen if I directly wrote

```
xxx = np.load('file_name.npz,mmap_mode="r")['arr_0'][0][0][0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mmap_mode` does not work with a `npz` file.  An `npz` is a `zip` archive.  That is, it contains `npy` files, one per `key`.  You can see this by looking at the `npz` file with a OS archive manager tool.

I'm a little surprised that your `load` call doesn't raise an error, but looking at the code I see that it dispatches to `NpzFile` loader without even looking at the `mmap_mode` parameter.

To use `mmap`, you'll have to extract `arr_0.npy` (again using the OS tool), and use `load` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Memory-mapping only works with arrays stored in a *binary file* on disk (see [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html#numpy.memmap)), not with compressed archives like `.npz`.

So when you perform `xxx = np.load('file_name.npz', mmap_mode='r')`, you load the NpzFile object with the following attributes:

```
xxx.__dict__
>>> {'_files': ['arr_0.npy'],
     'files': ['arr_0'],
     'allow_pickle': False,
     'pickle_kwargs': {...},
     'zip': <zipfile.ZipFile file=<_io.BufferedReader name='/path/to/xxx_npz/file/file_name.npz'> mode='r'>,
     'f': <numpy.lib.npyio.BagObj at ...>,
     'fid': <_io.BufferedReader name='/path/to/xxx_npz/file/file_name.npz'>}
```

And when you do `xxx['arr_0']`, it loads the corresponding attribute of your NpzFile object – which in your case is the full numpy array!

Instead, you can extract the `.npz` file using:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('path/to/file_name.npz', 'r') as f:
    f.extractall(path='path/where/you/want/to/extract', members=['arr_0.npy'])
```

And then execute:

```
xxx = np.load('path/to/arr_0.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```

See [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/timeseriesAI/tsai/blob/master/tutorial_nbs/00_How_to_efficiently_work_with_very_large_numpy_arrays.ipynb) for a useful resource on using memory maps in numpy.